# How do I import libraries in my project in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

So when I try to run my .jar file on the command line, I keep getting a Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils .

I have looked at some answers on here and nothing seems to help or maybe I am just not understanding it correctly.

I have tried added it to my libraries in my properties but that's not helping.

Comment: I’m assuming your code compiles within Netbeans. If it doesn’t, stop reading here and get a Netbeans crash course elsewhere. To run your code from an external console/terminal, the apache commons jar needs to be in your classpath, specified by Java classpath settings in your environment or command line.

Comment: How do I find the class path? Sorry if I sound dumb, I haven't done this before

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: @Timir will this work if I want someone else to run it on there machine?

Comment: @Timir I don't think that will help, I am building it as a .jar and running it on the command line.

Comment: Not surprising, that’s a very common use case. The classpath is how you tell the Java runtime to locate dependencies. Those dependencies may simply be classes or packaged a jar. Also, your dependencies may have dependencies, in which case they should be included in your classpath too.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem. You are asking about Y but what you are really trying to do is X. I imagine the real problem you are trying to solve is "make program automatically load its own dependencies", yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a library folder and add your imports in there. Right-click on your project and click properties then go to libraries and add the libraries from your library folder.